# How to exit the recovery console?

Tags: recovery-mode

I was having problems with Ubuntu 11.04 freezing up with Firefox, then it was freezing up with other applications as well.

At login I tried Recovery Console and now I can't get out of it. Ubuntu 11.04 is installed on my desktop which is an Acer Aspire AM5100-E5401A with a AMD Phenom 64 Quad core.

Comment: See also here: http://askubuntu.com/a/92558/3940

Answer (score 8):

Just run the command `exit` and you will exit from the recovery console.

Comment: I've been looking around for this particular problem but, what happens when exit does nothing? Like it just freezes I can't ctrl+ anything to get out...

Answer (score 3):

Simply type `reboot`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever, reboot command asks for root so I entered sudo reboot, but as before the problem is that I in a loop, meaning it brings me back to the white command screen upper left hand corner. I want to go to normal login.

Comment: In this case, I doubt you were in the recovery mode in the first place. Can you elaborate on the steps after selecting the recovery mode from Grub menu.

Comment: @Dan Did you anything in grub-config to get into the recovery console? Or you just selected the option from grub option menu?