# How to exit recovery console?

Tags: recovery-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exit the recovery console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58168/how-to-exit-the-recovery-console)

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 11.10 two days ago and by accident I started on recovery console mode and now I cannot get out of it. I tried reboot and enter and it said: need to be root. How can I start it normally again? I have no experience with commands and stuff. Thank you.