# how to return to the recovery mode menu from shell

Tags: recovery-mode

After dropping to root shell from recovery mode how to return to the recovery mode menu?

I have only wifi connection and I do not know what Repair broken packeges menu entry does so I want to drop to shell and connect to my router then come back to the menu and press that recover broken packages item.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exit recovery console?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93459/how-to-exit-recovery-console) also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

Comment: The answers are same. However, the concerns are different. When you say "exit" I expect getting out of the recovery mode totally That is why I didn't try it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could press Ctrl+D or type "exit" in the root shell, which will bring back recovery menu